# How can I know what command is running when I move the point or select something?

Tags: hooks

One example: I select something, then the minibuffer give me some response. For example, in `markdown-preview-mode` I select a paragraph then the minibuffer shows me the paragraph with `<p>` in each end.

Another example: I move the point onto some `defn` in `clojure-mode` or `funtion` in `js-mode` or `def` in `python-mode`, then the minibuffer shows me the `doc` or `usage` of the function.

So what command cause this behavior? Is this a hook? If so, which hook, and hook to what? How could I know that?

Comment: `M-x eldoc-mode`

Comment: @Drew Thanks.  Does `eldoc-mode` do the suggestions in minibuffer?
 I didn't run this minor mode. If I try to run it in `js-mode`, `markdown-preview-mode`, it will prompt to me `There is no ElDoc support in this buffer`.

Comment: You could try setting `debug-on-message` (see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Explicit-Debug.html ) if you know what exact message you are going to see after some mouse movement. However, the experiences you describe may not be all caused by the same code.

Comment: As of Emacs 25.1 `global-eldoc-mode` is enabled by default. Perhaps `js-mode` and `markdown-preview-mode` are doing their own thing though.

Comment: @wvxvw: I concur with that as a general approach when messages are involved, as the backtrace tends to provide the missing information. Would you like to turn your comment into an Answer?